# When writing Eclipse plugins, what is the correct way for checking if an IEditorPart is a Java editor?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am writing Eclipse plugins for Java, and have the following problem:

Given an IEditorPart, I need to check if it is a java editor.

I could do (IEditor instanceof JavaEditor),
but JavaEditor is an org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor,
which falls under the JDT's "internal" classes.

Is there a smarter and safer way to do this? I'm not sure why there is no non-internal interface for this.

Comment: Check it for what reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should test the id of the IEditorPart:

```
private boolean isJavaEditor(IWorkbenchPartReference ref) {
    if (ref == null) {
        return false; }

    String JavaDoc id= ref.getId();
    return JavaUI.ID_CF_EDITOR.equals(id) || JavaUI.ID_CU_EDITOR.equals(id);
}
```

Testing the instance was [only needed in eclipse3.1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84862).

[alt text http://blogs.zdnet.com/images/Burnette_DSCN0599.JPG](http://blogs.zdnet.com/images/Burnette_DSCN0599.JPG)

[`JavaUI`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84862) is the main access point to the Java user interface components. It allows you to programmatically open editors on Java elements, open a Java or Java Browsing perspective,  and open package and type prompter dialogs.

[`JavaUI`](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/JavaUI.html) is the central access point for the Java UI plug-in (id "`org.eclipse.jdt.ui`")

You can see that kind of utility function ("`isJavaEditor()`") used for instance in [`ASTProvider`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/ASTProvider.java.htm).

The mechanism of identification here is indeed simple String comparison.

Anyway, you are wise to avoid cast comparison with internal class: it has been listed as [one of the 10 common errors in plugins development](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/01/top-10-mistakes-in-eclipse-plug-in.html) ;) .

Comment: Seems reliable, but I have to say that's a really bizarre mechanism... String comparisons? 
I wish the JDT exposed more materials.

Comment: Yes, as far as know, every uid mechanism for plugins are based on String

Answer (score 0):

One strategy might be to use [JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(IEditorPart)](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/JavaUI.html#getEditorInputJavaElement(org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput)):

```
// given IEditorPart editor
IJavaElement elt = JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(editor.getEditorInput());
if (elt != null) {
    // editor is a Java editor
}
```

The method returns `null` if the editor input is not in fact a Java element.